# If statement not working when passing props to functional component using Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I have just started to learn React and the if statement I have inside my functional component (in  **ChooseInputType.js** shown below) is returning 'false' even though I would expect it to return 'true'. My simplified code is below - can anyone spot the problem? I would like to use Hooks rather than Classes if that's relevant!

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ChooseInputType from './ChooseInputType';

function App(){
    return(
        <ChooseInputType 
            type="select"
        ></ChooseInputType >
);
}
```

**ChooseInputType.js**

```
function ChooseInputType({type}){
    if({type} ==='select'){
        return (<div>True: Type is {type} </div>);
    else{
        return (<div>False: Type is {type} </div>);
    }
}
export default ChooseInputType;
```

As you can see from Form.js above, the type property being passed into the ChooseInputType component is equal to "select" and yet the result returned is incorrectly displaying the following:

**Result**

```
False: Type is select
```

This does not happen if I create a variable within ChooseInputType.js (as below), so it must be something about the way I'm passing the type property to the ChooseInputType component?

```
    function ChooseInputType({type}){
    //I have removed the props part by creating a type variable here
        const type="select";
        if(type ==='select'){
            return (<div>True</div>);
        else{
            return (<div>False</div>);
        }
    }
    export default ChooseInputType;
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers!

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: remove the `{}` from `if({type} ==='select'){` to become `if(type ==='select'){`

Comment: Remember: in JSX `{}` is used to denote a javascript variable or expression, but outside of JSX it is object syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line below where you are using `{type}` to compare to 'select'

```
if({type} ==='select')
```

it should simply be

```
if(type ==='select')
```

Comment: Thanks Sumedh - this was a very clear answer and it works. Thanks for your speedy response - this has helped me move on with my project! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Don't wrap it in brackets after its been deconstructed

This alone should work. The curly brackets mean you are getting the value of the key `type` from your object. you should not use brackets around it when you use it after because thats like putting it back inside an object and `{type: 'select'} !== 'select'` but deconstructed type is equal to 'select'

```
    function ChooseInputType({type}){
        if(type ==='select'){
            return (<div>True</div>);
        else{
            return (<div>False</div>);
        }
    }
    export default ChooseInputType;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me here! And for giving an explanation too. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function ChooseInputType({type}){
    if({type} ==='select'){ // change {type} to type
        return (<div>True: Type is {type} </div>);
    else{
        return (<div>False: Type is {type} </div>);
    }
}
export default ChooseInputType;
```

This does not work because you've already extracted `type` from `props` at argument and it's no longer an object.

Here's a good medium post to read about destructing objects: https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8

Comment: Thank you Shawn for providing some reading for me to understand the solution in more depth :)